# how to bring the control out of the sql statement once the where condition is met in C#

Tags: c#

```
 Stream stream = SystemStreams.Where(st => st.getName().Equals(s.OBJECT_NAME))
                              .Single();
```

in the above query in C# even if my condition of where clause is met my program reads all the records. due to which its becoming really slow. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Just use [**`FirstOrDefault()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301896.aspx) instead:

```
Stream stream = SystemStreams.Where(st => st.getName().Equals(s.OBJECT_NAME))
                             .FirstOrDefault();
```

or even shorter:

```
Stream stream = SystemStreams.FirstOrDefault(st => st.getName().Equals(s.OBJECT_NAME))
```

Note that `FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` if no match is found, otherwise the first item that matches.

**Edit in response to comments:**

In the SQL providers I have looked at `Single()` is translated to

```
SELECT TOP 2 bar,baz from foo where <some condition>
```

this means if there is only one match you still have to compare **all records** to try and find that second match - this is necessary because `Single()` must throw an exception if there is no match at all or more than one match.

`FirstOrDefault()` on the other hand gets translated to

```
SELECT TOP 1 bar,baz from foo where <some condition>
```

This means it can stop after the first match and return `null` or the record accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure that this is correct? How will the st.getName() method be converted into SQL? it can only be evaluated once the whole record it fetched.

Comment: It should be noted, though, that this is different than the OP's code. His will throw if there are more than one `st` that has the same `s.OBJECT_NAME` and yours won't care and grab the first one.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that `Single` has to evaluate the entire set of records in order to ensure that only a single matching item is in them. `FirstOrDefault` doesn't have to do this, but also has different semantics.

Comment: @jb: I don't see any other way: `Single()` will be translated to `select top 2 ...` so if there is only one matching record in the table you **still** would have to look at all of them to try and find the second one. This is neccessary to find out whether an exception should be thrown. `FirstOrDefault()` though will stop after it finds the match since it translates to `select top 1 ..`

Comment: @BrokenGlass, you already got my +1 and I'm not sure there is a better way around it, just wanted to point out the difference if the OP didn't realize.

Answer (score 1):

use SystemStreams.FirstOrDefault(query) instead of .Where

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because your function **getName()** cannot be converted from an expression to a SQL statement, the whole record must be fetched and the where clause is evaluated locally (not on the database).